# Importing into Photos: Unable to get metadata

Tags: photos, metadata

I'm switching to using Photos and I'm trying to import all my old photos. I select them all in Finder and drag them into Photos, some import and for some I get the error "Unable to get metadata". However, if I individually select any of the files that gave an error and drag them in, they import without errors.

I still have several thousand to import and I don't want to have to find them individually and drag them in, any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to work around this issue/bug by dragging the photos from Finder into Photos manually in batches (e.g. 200 or 300 pictures at once).

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by moving the photo to a different disk or volume first then importing.

Answer (score 0):

That's an annoying bug. You could try to work around the bug by building an Automator recipe that takes your images on at a time and loads them each into Photos.app.